# use macOS Mojave and Xcode 10.0 to build a iOS framework successfully but the framework file is 0KB

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm working on a iOS framework project. Before I updated my macOS to Mojave, this iOS framework project did not have any problem. But when the macOS was updated and xcode installed a patch, this framework project could build successfully but the compiled framework file is 0KB.

How do I solve this problem?

### this is the aggregate script:

```js
FMK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
INSTALL_DIR=${SRCROOT}/Products/${FMK_NAME}.framework
WRK_DIR=build
DEVICE_DIR=${WRK_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/${FMK_NAME}.framework
SIMULATOR_DIR=${WRK_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/${FMK_NAME}.framework
xcodebuild -configuration "Release" -target "${FMK_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 clean build
xcodebuild -configuration "Release" -target "${FMK_NAME}" -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 clean build
if [ -d "${INSTALL_DIR}" ]
then
rm -rf "${INSTALL_DIR}"
fi

mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}"

cp -R "${DEVICE_DIR}/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/"
lipo -create "${DEVICE_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}" "${SIMULATOR_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}" -output "${INSTALL_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}"

rm -r "${WRK_DIR}"

open "${SRCROOT}/Products/"
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong when I change the script